# Google Spreadsheet : How to feed two sheets into a single pivot table?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets with identical columns. I would like a single pivot table that combines the data together. Here is a sample data set:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b_RWeOKghBA9w72ppEeCoQiS1cTmr2GpsfQB6TrwfeE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot tables only let you select a single range. Just combine the data from each sheet into a separate "helper" sheet and reference that range for your pivot table.

Comment: Thanks for the insight yet how do I create a helper sheet to combine the data as the source sheets change in data?